# Rails, handle email addresses for user objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I want to accomplish the following with email_addresses and users:

- Allow users to sign up with an email address and password
- Send a confirmation email to users
- Allow users to log in with their email and password

Would this be best done by just having just an email address string attached to a user as a DB attribute? Or should I use a separate **email_address** table with user_id?

Also, is there a gem that works well for this, or should I just do it from scratch?

Comment: It's good to do it from scratch, just to understand how it works. But in a real app, you should use a gem (devise, for example)

Comment: "should I use a separate email_address table with user_id" - depends. Will your app support users having multiple email addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to easily manage the user authentication and sending of registration emails, you should check the `sorcery` gem:
https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/wiki/Simple-Password-Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Also need to mention [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) here. Widely used for this kind of problem.